# Bibliography last names in small-caps for Historische Zeitschrift package

Tags: biblatex, historische-zeitschrift

I am using slightly customised `Historische Zeitschrift` package and now publisher wants me to make few more changes:

1. Authors, editors etc. names need to be in small capps.
2. If the author or editor is modern the last names need to appear first, than comma than first name followed by colon.
3. If the author is ancient, his first and last name need to stay in this order and be in small caps too followed by colon.
4. If there are more authors or editors they need to be separated by semicolon.
5. The word Ed. (Hrsg.) needs to stay in normal font (not small-caps)

Here is the example how this should look like:

[image: How it should look like]

Please note that I already solved the problem of ancient author names staying in this order (first than last name) by adding braces around their names in bibliography like this: `{{Evagrius Scholasticus}}`

This is my MWE:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{
    colorlinks,
     citecolor=black,
     filecolor=black,
     linkcolor=black,
     urlcolor=black
}
\usepackage{chngcntr}
\counterwithin*{footnote}{section}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib} 
@incollection{athanasius1998,
    Address = {Berlin/New York},
    Author = {{Athanasius Alexandrinus}},
    Booktitle = {Athanasius Werke - Die dogmatischen Schriften},
    Call-Number = {TH: Vb 17.02-1.1.2},
    Date-Added = {2010-10-16 13:24:30 +0200},
    Date-Modified = {2014-03-13 17:12:32 +0000},
    Editor = {Marin Tetz and others},
    Keywords = {source},
    Pages = {109-175},
    Publisher = {Walter de Gruyter},
    Read = {No},
    Series = {Urkunden zur Geschichte des Arianischen Streites 318-328},
    Shortauthor = {Ath.},
    Shorttitle = {Ar. 1},
    Usera = {SCh},
    Title = {Oratio I contra Arianos},
    Volume = {1, Tl. 1, Lfg. 2},
    Year = {1998}}
@incollection{evagrius2011,
    Address = {Paris},
    Author = {{Evagrius Scholasticus}},
    Booktitle = {{\'E}vagre Le Scholastique: Histoire Eccl{\'e}siastique - Livres I-III},
    Call-Number = {TH: Va1.05/542},
    Date-Added = {2013-08-24 12:11:20 +0000},
    Date-Modified = {2014-03-30 11:54:31 +0000},
    Editor = {Joseph Bidez and Leon Parmentier},
    Keywords = {source},
    Publisher = {Les {\'E}ditions du Cerf},
    Series = {Sources chr{\'e}tiennes},
    Shortauthor = {Evagr.},
    Shorttitle = {h.e.},
    Title = {Historia ecclesiastica},
    Usera = {SCh},
    Volume = {542},
    Year = {2011}}
@book{hahn1897,
    Address = {Breslau},
    Call-Number = {TH: EbI30/3},
    Date-Added = {2010-11-16 12:32:21 +0100},
    Date-Modified = {2014-06-28 13:16:22 +0000},
    Edition = {3},
    Editor = {August Hahn and Ludwig Hahn},
    Keywords = {source; law},
    Publisher = {Verlag von E. Morgenstern},
    Shortauthor = {Hahn},
    Shorttitle = {Symbole},
    Title = {Bibliothek der Symbole und Glaubensregeln der Alten Kirche},
    Year = {1897}}@book{hahn1897,
    Address = {Breslau},
    Call-Number = {TH: EbI30/3},
    Date-Added = {2010-11-16 12:32:21 +0100},
    Date-Modified = {2014-06-28 13:16:22 +0000},
    Edition = {3},
    Editor = {August Hahn and Ludwig Hahn},
    Keywords = {source; law},
    Publisher = {Verlag von E. Morgenstern},
    Shortauthor = {Hahn},
    Shorttitle = {Symbole},
    Title = {Bibliothek der Symbole und Glaubensregeln der Alten Kirche},
    Year = {1897}}
@incollection{gregoire1974,
    Address = {Paris},
    Author = {{Gregorius Nazianzenus}},
    Booktitle = {Lettres th{\'e}ologiques},
    Call-Number = {TH: Va 1.05 208},
    Date-Added = {2010-04-22 16:22:42 +0200},
    Date-Modified = {2014-03-30 11:54:28 +0000},
    Editor = {Paul Gallay},
    Keywords = {source},
    Pages = {87-95},
    Publisher = {Les {\'E}ditions du Cerf},
    Series = {Sources chr{\'e}tiennes},
    Shortauthor = {{Gr. Naz.}},
    Shorttitle = {ep. 202},
    Title = {Epistula 202: Ad Nectarium Constantinopolitanum},
    Usera = {SCh},
    Volume = {208},
    Year = {1974}}
@incollection{gregorius1981,
    Address = {Paris},
    Author = {{Gregorius Nazianzenus}},
    Booktitle = {Discours 24-26},
    Date-Added = {2014-05-29 12:04:21 +0000},
    Date-Modified = {2014-05-29 12:05:35 +0000},
    Editor = {Justin Mossay},
    Keywords = {source},
    Pages = {40-85},
    Publisher = {Les {\'E}ditions du Cerf},
    Series = {Sources chr{\'e}tiennes},
    Shortauthor = {{Gr. Naz.}},
    Shorttitle = {or. 24},
    Title = {Oratio 24: In laudem s. Cypriani},
    Usera = {SCh},
    Volume = {284},
    Year = {1980}}
@incollection{gregorius1990,
    Address = {Paris},
    Author = {{Gregorius Nazianzenus}},
    Booktitle = {Discours 38-41},
    Date-Added = {2014-03-27 09:58:33 +0000},
    Date-Modified = {2014-03-30 11:53:58 +0000},
    Editor = {Claudio Moreschini},
    Keywords = {source},
    Pages = {104-148},
    Publisher = {Les {\'E}ditions du Cerf},
    Series = {Sources chr{\'e}tiennes},
    Shortauthor = {{Gr. Naz.}},
    Shorttitle = {or. 38},
    Title = {Oratio 38: In Theophania},
    Usera = {SCh},
    Volume = {358},
    Year = {1990}}
@incollection{gregorius1979/1,
    Address = {Paris},
    Author = {{Gregorius Nazianzenus}},
    Booktitle = {Discours 27-31},
    Date-Added = {2014-03-27 09:54:29 +0000},
    Date-Modified = {2014-03-30 18:41:48 +0000},
    Editor = {Paul Gallay},
    Keywords = {source},
    Pages = {176-225},
    Publisher = {Les {\'E}ditions du Cerf},
    Series = {Sources chr{\'e}tiennes},
    Shortauthor = {{Gr. Naz.}},
    Shorttitle = {or. 29},
    Title = {Oratio 29: Theologica III},
    Usera = {SCh},
    Volume = {250},
    Year = {1979}}

@incollection{gregoire1978/2,
    Address = {Paris},
    Author = {{Gregorius Nazianzenus}},
    Booktitle = {Discours 27-31},
    Call-Number = {TH: Va 1.05 250},
    Date-Added = {2014-03-26 18:56:20 +0000},
    Date-Modified = {2014-03-30 11:54:18 +0000},
    Editor = {Paul Gallay},
    Keywords = {source},
    Pages = {276-343},
    Publisher = {Les {\'E}ditions du Cerf},
    Series = {Sources chr{\'e}tiennes},
    Shortauthor = {{Gr. Naz.}},
    Shorttitle = {or. 31},
    Title = {Oratio 31: Theologica V},
    Usera = {SCh},
    Volume = {250},
    Year = {1978}}

@incollection{gregorius1978,
    Address = {Paris},
    Author = {{Gregorius Nazianzenus}},
    Booktitle = {Discours 1-3},
    Date-Added = {2014-03-26 18:48:54 +0000},
    Date-Modified = {2014-03-30 18:42:08 +0000},
    Keywords = {source},
    Pages = {84-241},
    Publisher = {Les {\'E}ditions du Cerf},
    Series = {Sources chr{\'e}tiennes},
    Shortauthor = {{Gr. Naz.}},
    Shorttitle = {or. 2},
    Title = {Oratio 2: Apologetica},
    Usera = {SCh},
    Volume = {247},
    Year = {1978}}

@incollection{gregorius1990/2,
    Address = {Paris},
    Author = {{Gregorius Nazianzenus}},
    Booktitle = {Discours 38-41},
    Date-Added = {2014-03-26 17:58:16 +0000},
    Date-Modified = {2014-03-30 11:53:48 +0000},
    Editor = {Claudio Moreschini},
    Keywords = {source},
    Pages = {150-197},
    Publisher = {Les {\'E}ditions du Cerf},
    Series = {Sources chr{\'e}tiennes},
    Shortauthor = {{Gr. Naz.}},
    Shorttitle = {or. 39},
    Title = {Oratio 39: In sancta lumina},
    Usera = {SCh},
    Volume = {358},
    Year = {1990}}

@incollection{gregorius1992,
    Address = {Paris},
    Author = {{Gregorius Nazianzenus}},
    Booktitle = {Discours 42-43},
    Date-Added = {2014-03-26 17:58:15 +0000},
    Date-Modified = {2014-03-30 11:53:44 +0000},
    Editor = {Jean Bernardi},
    Keywords = {source},
    Pages = {48-115},
    Publisher = {Les {\'E}ditions du Cerf},
    Series = {Sources chr{\'e}tiennes},
    Shortauthor = {{Gr. Naz.}},
    Shorttitle = {or. 42},
    Title = {Oratio 42: Supremum vale},
    Usera = {SCh},
    Volume = {384},
    Year = {1992}}

@incollection{gregorius1990/1,
    Address = {Paris},
    Author = {{Gregorius Nazianzenus}},
    Booktitle = {Discours 38-41},
    Date-Added = {2014-03-26 17:58:15 +0000},
    Date-Modified = {2014-03-30 18:41:25 +0000},
    Editor = {Claudio Moreschini},
    Keywords = {source},
    Pages = {198-311},
    Publisher = {Les {\'E}ditions du Cerf},
    Series = {Sources chr{\'e}tiennes},
    Shortauthor = {{Gr. Naz.}},
    Shorttitle = {or. 40},
    Title = {Oratio 40: In sanctum baptisma},
    Usera = {SCh},
    Volume = {358},
    Year = {1990}}

@incollection{gregorius1980/1,
    Address = {Paris},
    Author = {{Gregorius Nazianzenus}},
    Booktitle = {Discours 20-23},
    Date-Added = {2014-03-26 17:42:35 +0000},
    Date-Modified = {2014-03-30 11:54:01 +0000},
    Editor = {Justin Mossay},
    Keywords = {source},
    Pages = {220-258},
    Publisher = {Les {\'E}ditions du Cerf},
    Series = {Sources chr{\'e}tiennes},
    Shortauthor = {{Gr. Naz.}},
    Shorttitle = {or. 22},
    Title = {Oratio 22: De pace II},
    Usera = {SCh},
    Volume = {270},
    Year = {1980}}

@incollection{gregorius1978/1,
    Address = {Paris},
    Author = {{Gregorius Nazianzenus}},
    Booktitle = {Discours 1-3},
    Date-Added = {2014-03-26 17:42:34 +0000},
    Date-Modified = {2014-03-30 18:41:59 +0000},
    Keywords = {source},
    Pages = {241-255},
    Publisher = {Les {\'E}ditions du Cerf},
    Series = {Sources chr{\'e}tiennes},
    Shortauthor = {{Gr. Naz.}},
    Shorttitle = {or. 3},
    Title = {Oratio 3: Ad eos qui ipsum acciverant nec occurrerant},
    Usera = {SCh},
    Volume = {247},
    Year = {1978}}

@book{moreschini1997,
    Address = {Oxford},
    Author = {{Gregorius Nazianzenus}},
    Call-Number = {Googlebooks},
    Date-Added = {2014-03-26 15:07:53 +0000},
    Date-Modified = {2014-03-26 15:14:45 +0000},
    Editor = {Claudio Moreschini and},
    Keywords = {source},
    Publisher = {Clarendon Press},
    Series = {Oxford Theological Monographs},
    Title = {St. Gregory of Nazianzus: \textit{Poemata Arcana}},
    Translator = {Donald Sykes},
    Year = {1997}}

@book{vermes2012,
    Address = {London},
    Author = {Geza Vermes},
    Date-Added = {2017-07-22 09:28:39 +0000},
    Date-Modified = {2017-07-22 09:29:46 +0000},
    Keywords = {secondary},
    Publisher = {Lane},
    Title = {Christian beginnings: From Nazareth to Nicaea (AD 30 - 325)},
    Year = {2012}}

@article{lucchesi1999,
    Author = {Enzo Lucchesi},
    Call-Number = {nisam procitao},
    Date-Added = {2016-06-27 14:06:18 +0000},
    Date-Modified = {2016-06-27 14:08:55 +0000},
    Journal = {Vigiliae christianae},
    Keywords = {secondary},
    Number = {3},
    Pages = {323-324},
    Title = {Trois {\'e}loges coptes de Jean-Baptiste attribu{\'e}s {\`a} Athanase, Th{\'e}ophile et Cyrille d'Alexandrie},
    Volume = {53},
    Year = {1999}}

@book{riall1987,
    Address = {Cincinnati},
    Author = {Robert Archie Riall},
    Date-Added = {2016-06-27 13:47:03 +0000},
    Date-Modified = {2016-06-27 13:49:43 +0000},
    Keywords = {secondary},
    Publisher = {University of Cincinnati},
    Title = {Athanasius Bishop of Alexandria: The Politics of Spirituality},
    Year = {1987}}

@article{leemans2000,
    Author = {Johan Leemans},
    Call-Number = {4653},
    Date-Added = {2016-06-27 13:37:05 +0000},
    Date-Modified = {2016-06-27 13:39:50 +0000},
    Journal = {Sacris Erudiri: A Yournal on the Inheritance of Early and Medieval Christianity},
    Keywords = {secondary},
    Pages = {105-217},
    Title = {Thirteen Years of Athanasius Research (1985-1998): A Survey and Bibliography},
    Volume = {39},
    Year = {2000}}

@book{white1996,
    Address = {Cambridge},
    Author = {{Gregorius Nazianzenus}},
    Call-Number = {Googlebooks},
    Date-Added = {2014-03-26 15:05:53 +0000},
    Date-Modified = {2014-03-26 15:07:22 +0000},
    Editor = {Carolinne White},
    Keywords = {source},
    Publisher = {Cambridge University Press},
    Title = {Gregory of Nazianzus: Autobiographical Poems},
    Translator = {Carolline White},
    Year = {1996}}
@book{gregorius1862,
    Address = {Parisiis},
    Author = {{Gregorius Nazianzenus}},
    Call-Number = {PDF},
    Date-Added = {2014-03-15 15:58:32 +0000},
    Date-Modified = {2014-03-31 08:01:30 +0000},
    Editor = {Jacques Paul Migne},
    Keywords = {source},
    Publisher = {Accurante J.-P. Migne},
    Series = {Patrologiae cursus completus: Series Graeca},
    Shortauthor = {{Gr. Naz.}},
    Shorttitle = {hym. 30},
    Title = {Hymnus 30: Ad Deum},
    Usera = {PG},
    Volume = {37},
    Year = {1862}}
@incollection{gregorius1980,
    Address = {Paris},
    Author = {{Gregorius Nazianzenus}},
    Booktitle = {Discours 20-23},
    Date-Added = {2013-04-25 14:10:40 +0000},
    Date-Modified = {2014-03-30 11:54:04 +0000},
    Editor = {Justin Mossay},
    Keywords = {source},
    Pages = {110-193},
    Publisher = {Les {\'E}ditions du Cerf},
    Series = {Sources chr{\'e}tiennes},
    Shortauthor = {{Gr. Naz.}},
    Shorttitle = {or. 21},
    Title = {Oratio 21: In laudem Athanasii},
    Usera = {SCh},
    Volume = {270},
    Year = {1980}}
@incollection{gregoire1974/2,
    Address = {Paris},
    Author = {{Gregorius Nazianzenus}},
    Booktitle = {Lettres th{\'e}ologiques},
    Call-Number = {TH: Va 1.05 208},
    Date-Added = {2012-05-04 16:46:23 +0200},
    Date-Modified = {2014-03-30 11:54:26 +0000},
    Editor = {Paul Gallay},
    Keywords = {source},
    Pages = {37-69},
    Publisher = {Les {\'E}ditions du Cerf},
    Series = {Sources chr{\'e}tiennes},
    Shortauthor = {{Gr. Naz.}},
    Shorttitle = {ep. 101},
    Title = {Epistula 101: Ad Cledonium presbyterum contra Apollinarium},
    Usera = {SCh},
    Volume = {208},
    Year = {1974}}
\end{filecontents}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[style=historische-zeitschrift, maxnames=2, hyperref=true, backref=true, backrefstyle=none, backend=bibtex,idemtracker=true]{biblatex}
\bibliography{\jobname}
% HISTORISCHE ZEITSCHRIFT - FIXING "( HRSG.)" TO " (HRSG.)"%
%
\makeatletter%
\renewbibmacro*{editorstrg}{%
  \ifthenelse{\value{editor}>1\OR\ifandothers{editor}}%
    {\bibstring[\mkbibparens]{editors}}%
    {\bibstring[\mkbibparens]{editor}}}%
\makeatother%
%
% HISTORISCHE ZEITSCHRIFT - PUBLISHER IN BIBLIOGRAPHY NOT OMMITED%
%
\makeatletter%
\renewbibmacro*{publisher+location+year}{%
  \printlist{location}:%
  \setunit*{\addspace}%
  \printlist{publisher}\addcomma%
  \setunit*{\addspace}%
  \printfield{year}%
  \newunit}%
\makeatother%
%
% HISTORISCHE ZEITSCHRIFT - NO PAGES IN INCOLLECTION FOOTNOTES BUT PAGES IN BIBLIOGRAPHY%
%
\renewbibmacro*{chapter+pages}{%
    \printfield{chapter}%
    \newunit}%
% 
% HISTORISCHE ZEITSCHRIFT - NO PAGES IN ARTICLE FOOTNOTES BUT PAGES IN BIBLIOGRAPHY%
%
\newbibmacro*{onlypages}{%
  \printfield{chapter}%
  \newunit}
\DeclareBibliographyDriver{article}{%
  \usebibmacro{bibindex}%
  \usebibmacro{author/editor}%
  \setunit{\labelnamepunct}\newblock
  \usebibmacro{title}%
  \newunit
  \usebibmacro{byauthor}%
  \newunit
  \printlist{language}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{byeditor+others}%
%     \newunit\newblock
  \setunit{\addcomma\space}%
  \usebibmacro{in:}%
  \usebibmacro{journal+issuetitle}%
%     \newunit\newblock
  \setunit*{\addcomma\space}%
  \printfield{note}%
%     \newunit\newblock
  \setunit*{\newunitpunct}%
\usebibmacro{onlypages}%
  \newunit\newblock%
  \usebibmacro{doi+eprint+url}%
  \newunit\newblock%
  \printfield{addendum}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{pageref}%
  \usebibmacro{finentry}}
%
% HISTORISCHE ZEITSCHRIFT - ADDING ZITIERT AUF INSTEAD OF SIEHE S. IN BIBLIOGRAPHY
%
\DefineBibliographyStrings{ngerman}{
  backrefpage  = {Zitiert auf S\adddot},
  backrefpages = {Zitiert auf S\adddot},
}
%
\begin{document}
\section{First section}
\blindtext\footcite[See][S. 56]{white1996}
\blindtext\footcite[See][S. 22]{evagrius2011}
\blindtext\footcite[See][S. 56]{moreschini1997}
\pagebreak
\section{Second section}
\blindtext\footcite[See][S. 56]{vermes2012}
\blindtext\footcite[See][S. 56]{lucchesi1999}
\blindtext\footcite[See][S. 12]{hahn1897}
\pagebreak
\section{Third section}
\blindtext\footcite[See][S. 11]{athanasius1998}
\blindtext\footcite[See][S. 12]{leemans2000}
\pagebreak
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

I tried playing with `name:last-first` macro but it didn't work :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With

```
\renewcommand*{\mkbibnamegiven}[1]{\textsc{#1}}
\renewcommand*{\mkbibnamefamily}[1]{\textsc{#1}}
\renewcommand*{\mkbibnameprefix}[1]{\textsc{#1}}
\renewcommand*{\mkbibnamesuffix}[1]{\textsc{#1}}
```

you will get authors/editors in small caps.

If you also want editors of `@incollection`s in small caps you additionally need

```
\DeclareNameAlias{upshape}{given-family}
```

You can get colons after the names with

```
\renewcommand*{\labelnamepunct}{\addcolon\space}
```

Several authors can be separated with semicolons by

```
\renewcommand*{\multinamedelim}{\addsemicolon\space}
\renewcommand*{\finalnamedelim}{\multinamedelim}
```

For the name order you need

```
\DeclareNameAlias{sortname}{family-given}
\DeclareNameAlias{default}{family-given}
```

and maybe even

```
\DeclareNameAlias{upshape}{family-given}
```

If you want to limit some of this to the bibliography only, but it into

```
\AtBeginBibliography{%

}
```

Comment: Thank you very much. This is indeed useful but this changes authors and editors names in the entire document. I need just to adjust bibliography at the end. Also this doesn't solve my other problems (first and last name order, colons etc.). I think that I will have to change something connected with the historische-zeitschrift package. The only problem is: I am not that advanced user that I am able to do this. Thanks for your help anyway! Maybe it will be useful for someone else.

Comment: @eklisiarh Sorry, I must have missed that you only wanted this in the bibliography. Have a look at the edited answer.

Comment: Thank you so much for expanding your answer! This now does everything I need except one small thing: Bibliography should have last names first separated by comma and followed by the first name (points 2 and 3 above). Can this also be done by renewing commands?

Comment: @eklisiarh Have a look at the edit.

Comment: @eklisiarh Try again with the new edit please. (In future you might want to consider asking only one question per question, that makes things a lot easier: https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/7425/35864)

Comment: Thank you this worked now. And you are right, in the future I will do as you suggested! Thank you again!